# How to check if a string starts with a tuple of substring and get the matched one?

Tags: python, string

I know how to check if a string starts with some substring like this:

```
text.startswith(("one", "two", "three", "four"))
```

but how to get which one is matched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex by building a pattern from the tuple and then extract the match:

```py
import re

subs = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
text = "three and a half"

if r := re.match("|".join(subs), text):
    print(r.group())
else:
    print("No match found")
```

Using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), this provides the same functionality as `str.startswith`.

---

For versions older than Python 3.8, use explicit assignment:

```py
r = re.match("|".join(subs), text)
if r:
    print(r.group())
```

Comment: thanks! i was optimizing my cone and this is the fastest way i found in the internet!

Answer (score 4):

You could loop over the elements in the tuple:

```py
mytuple = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
text = "one dog"
for i in mytuple:
    if text.startswith(i):
        print(i)
        break
>>> one
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> text = "two dogs"
>>> lst = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
>>> next((item for item in lst if text.startswith(item)),None)
'two'
```

`item for item in lst if text.startswith(item)` yields `item` if condition is `True`. `next` iterates manually on the expression at most once.

If no string matches, the expression returns `None`. First match ends the search.

Answer (score 0):

One line version. This will give the list of all words which appear in the start of `text`.

```
startMatches = [word for word in ("one","two","three","four") if word == text[:len(word)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a oneliner with list comprehension:

```
text = 'three-dimensional'
match_idxs = [i for i, substr in enumerate(("one", "two", "three", "four")) if text.startswith(substr)]
print('matching indexes: ', match_idxs)

>>> "matching indexes: [2]"
```